# Generate a random byte stream

Tags: c

I'm testing a network program that sends packet to a remote server using UDP/TCP, and for that,
I want to generate some random byte streams.

Here's the function:

```
unsigned char *gen_rdm_bytestream(int num_bytes)
{
    unsigned char *stream = malloc(num_bytes);
    /*
     * here how to generate?
     */
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: You may want to try using a standard library function that returns random numbers

Comment: After `malloc` memory is already `random` in some sense. It's not truly random but filled with _trash_. I think it should be enough for testing, I don't think you need crypto-strong random generator.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For each byte, you can call a random number generator function. The C standard provides the function `rand`. Before using it, you should initialize the random sequence with a call to `srand`.

`gen_rdm_bytestream` may then look something like that:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned char *gen_rdm_bytestream (size_t num_bytes)
{
  unsigned char *stream = malloc (num_bytes);
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
  {
    stream[i] = rand ();
  }

  return stream;
}

srand ((unsigned int) time (NULL));
```

Since `stream` is unsigned, if the value returned by `rand` is greater than `UCHAR_MAX`, she will be reduced (modulo `UCHAR_MAX`). Therefore you will get pseudo-random numbers between 0 and 255.

Comment: if the `nr` in `srand(nr)` is fixed, then the produced bytes are always the same, whatever the platform is, right?

Comment: @user138126: No necessarily, since every platform doesn't have the same random number generator. However, using the function `time` for instance would solve the problem.

Comment: You could ditch rand() and srand() and use arc4random() for a better result.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have [`int rand (void);`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/?kw=rand) function in C,

> Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX.
> RAND_MAX is a constant defined in <cstdlib>.

> This number is generated by an algorithm that returns a sequence of apparently non-related numbers each time it is called. This algorithm uses a seed to generate the series, which should be initialized to some distinctive value using function [srand().](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/)

**EDIT**:

As you are commenting, I have written a code for you that may help you to demonstrate, How to use rand(), the program and its output are:

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>  /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>    
int main (){
 int i=0;
 srand (time(NULL));
 printf("Five rand numbers: \n");
 for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
   printf("\n %d", rand());
 }
 printf("Five rand numbersb between 2 to 5: \n");
 for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
   printf("\n %d", (2 + rand()%4));
 }    
 return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
 Five rand numbers: 

 1482376850
 1746468296
 1429725746
 595545676
 1544987577

 Five rand numbers, between 2 to 5: 

 2
 5
 3
 4
 3
```

[**Codepad Link**](http://codepad.org/9pRLCgt2)

Comment: this is `int`, which are 4 bytes

Comment: @user138126 `int` size is depends on platform in C. in Linux system is for, you can check its size using sizeof(int) operator

Comment: @user138126 yes on  system see this code output: [**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/zumbb2ap)

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX, there is the [getrandom](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html) system call.

```c
#include <sys/random.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char * gen_rdm_bytestream(size_t const num_bytes) {
    unsigned char * const stream = malloc(num_bytes);
    getrandom(stream, num_bytes, 0);
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general function for producing random integer values in a given range:

```
#include <stdlib>

/**
 * Assumes srand has already been called
 */
int randInRange( int min, int max )
{
  double scale = 1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1);
  double range = max - min + 1;
  return min + (int) ( rand() * scale * range );
}
```

Leveraging this to create unsigned `char` values:

```
u_char randomByte()
{
  return (u_char) randInRange( 0, 255 );
}
```

So,

```
for ( i = 0; i < numBytes; i++ )
  stream[i] = randomByte();
```

Answer (score -1):

The following is an actually stream (std::istream) and uses the C++11 <random> library.

This is not particularly written to be fast, but it it's fun:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

class RandomBuf : public std::streambuf
{
 private:
  size_t m_size;
  std::array<char, 64> m_buf;
  std::mt19937_64 m_twister;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<char> m_dist;

 protected:
  int_type underflow() override {
    if (m_size == 0)
      return EOF;

    size_t size = std::min(m_size, m_buf.size());
    setg(&m_buf[0], &m_buf[0], &m_buf[size]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      m_buf[i] = m_dist(m_twister);
    m_size -= size;
    return 0;
  }

 public:
  RandomBuf(size_t size, char b, char e) : m_size(size), m_dist(b, e) { }
};

class Random : public std::istream
{
  private:
   RandomBuf m_streambuf;

  public:
   Random(size_t size, char b, char e) : m_streambuf(size, b, e)  {
     rdbuf(&m_streambuf);
   }
};

// Example usage:

int main()
{
  Random random(100, 'a', 'z'); // Create an istream that produces 100 pseudo-random characters in the interval ['a', 'z'].
  // Read random stream to a string:
  std::string str;
  random >> str;
  // Print result.
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

The output of this program (exactly, because the standard guarantees that a default constructed Mersenne twister has a given seed):

ugsyakganihodonwmktggixegfszuclgupylingbnscxadzqhjmhhyqtssbmctlpchqfflzfwhvjywmajtnkaxczrmtpnlvwmzxd

EDIT:

For extra bonus points I added a StreamHasher class:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/bIDCVTnJjkdafARo

Just the added classes:

```
class StreamHasherBuf : public std::streambuf
{
 private:
  size_t m_hash;
  std::array<char, 64> m_buf;   // The resulting hash value is a function of the size of the array!
  static constexpr size_t bufsize = std::tuple_size_v<decltype(m_buf)>;

  void add_and_reset_put_area()
  {
    boost::hash_combine(m_hash, boost::hash_range(pbase(), pptr()));
    setp(&m_buf[0], &m_buf[bufsize]);
  }

 protected:
  int_type overflow(int_type c) override
  {
    if (c != EOF)
    {
      if (pptr() == epptr())
        add_and_reset_put_area();
      *pptr() = c;
      pbump(1);
    }
    return 0;
  }

 public:
  StreamHasherBuf() : m_hash(0) { setp(&m_buf[0], &m_buf[bufsize]); }

  size_t hash()
  {
    add_and_reset_put_area();
    return m_hash;
  }
};

class StreamHasher : public std::ostream
{
 private:
  StreamHasherBuf m_streambuf;

 public:
  StreamHasher() { rdbuf(&m_streambuf); }
  size_t hash() { return m_streambuf.hash(); }
};
```

For example

```
int main()
{
  RandomBuf random(100, 'a', 'z'); // Create a streambuf that produces 100 pseudo-random characters in the interval ['a', 'z'].
  StreamHasher hasher;
  hasher << &random;
  std::cout << hasher.hash() << '\n';
}
```